# how to echo javascript value in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to print a value in PHP which is stored in JS variable.

```
 document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = '' + response;
```

I got the response in id `geo`

I could able to print through div

e.g `<div id ="geo"></div>`

I have a input tag I know I can use it as `id ="geo"` but i want to use it in value for example

```
<input id= "geocompleat" type="text" value="<?php $geo?>" >
```

Is there any way to get above JS value in to `$geo`?

EDIT:

geocompleat is used to get google geo places. i have input tag where i want to use geocompleate and geo location.

my webpage is detect the browser location and if we want to change the location then geocompleat will help to change the location. i tried below but its not working

```
<input id="geocompleat geo" type="text" name ="location">
```

so i am trying to to display the geo location in a `value=""` with php like value= ""

Comment: There is no jQuery here. the only way to make a PHP value the value of a JS variable is to use AJAX to send the value to a PHP script.

Comment: wow you are too fast please see i just edited

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the value of `geocompleat`?

Comment: no i cant touch id its should be in value, i am using id for getting geo places

Comment: `value="<?php $geo?>"` => `value="<?php echo $geo?>"` edit: may as well delete this now, seeing the [stealthy edit................................](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41492597/4)

Comment: @AseshaGeorge then don't post until you have the whole question XD

Comment: fred my problem how to get js value in $geo

Comment: `value="<?= $geo ?>"`, secondly, post data to the server, then its accessible by PHP. You request website, PHP is executed, page is send to user, page is shown to the user while Javascript is executeing. Hopefully you understand that PHP is already done here.

Comment: ALL Dont forget to give that `<input>` a `name="geo"` attribute, or submitting the form will not send this data

Comment: my concern is to print it. is there any possible to send the JS value to jquery ajax and pass to php?

Comment: You can change the value of the input with JS and then submit the form to a PHP script. Is that what you're after?

Comment: You can always just send the data using AJAX to a PHP script. Once there you can do what you like with it

Comment: ya see i am getting geo palaces in geocompleat id and geo location in geo i want to use both in one input tag.

Comment: [This might help...](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+send+a+ajax+request+in+jquery)

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Still not getting your actual requirement?

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the "response" content to the input, you can do it with javascript so you don't need to use php:

```
document.getElementById('your_input_id').value = response;
```

if you want to send your javascript data, you must make a AJAX GET/POST request.

Btw. you cannot use multiple values in html id attribute like this :

You can use only one variable :

```
<input id="geocompleat" type="text" name="location">
```

If you want to use multiple values, use the "class" attribute :

```
<input class="geocompleat geo" type="text" name="location">
```

Comment: can i use window.location.href="//myweb.com?geo_loc="+ geo; and get it in php

Comment: yes, sure, if the geo javascript variable is a simple string and not a javascript/json object (for example).

Comment: [objectHTMLInputElement]

Comment: get the value attribute by adding ".value" to the input object, like geo = element.value; to get the input value and not the input object.